# Does the iOS App Store display retina screenshots of iPad apps?

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

According to the [iTunes Connect guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html), I need to supply iPad screenshots following these dimensions:

> For best results, do not include the iPad status bar in your
>   screenshots and follow these requirements:
>
> - 1024x748 pixels for landscape (without status bar) minimum
> - 1024x768 pixels for landscape (full screen) maximum
> - 2048x1496 pixels for hi-res (without status bar) minimum
> - 2048x1536 pixels for hi-res landscape (full screen) maximum
> - 768x1004 pixels for portrait (without status bar) minimum
> - 768x1024 pixels for portrait (full screen) maximum
> - 1536x2008 pixels for hi-res portrait (without status bar) minimum
> - 1536x2048 pixels for hi-res portrait (full screen) maximum
> - 72 ppi, RGB, flattened, no transparency
> - High quality JPEG, TIFF or PNG image file format. ZIP-compressed TIFF    files are not acceptable.

However when I browse the App Store, I never get to see the hi res screenshots of my app, even when I'm a retina iOS device. So is it ok if I don't supply the hi res images?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175701)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Hmm I see. I agree with you. It makes sense to close questions like this, but on the other hand I think there's some value to people giving examples and personal experience to support their answers. (e.g. I have made a flashlight app on the App Store and have seen 100 other apps like that, you can too.)